# qmake adding header files from subfolders

Tags: c++, include, qmake, include-path

I am trying to generate a c++ project using qmake and compiling it under visual studio.
this project as a dependency to itk.
I made a .pri with a MyITK project in it:

```
MyITK {
CONFIG_FOUND += MyITK
INCLUDEPATH += $${PACKAGE_SOURCES}/Shared/MyITK
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $${PACKAGE_LIB}/MyITK
win32:LIBS += ITKIONIFTI-4.13.lib \ 
            ITKCommon-4.13.lib \
            ITKBiasCorrection-4.13.lib \
            ITKBioCell-4.13.lib \
```

etc

in the .pro of my project is like that:

```
CONFIG += staticlib MyITK

HEADERS += \
   myowncode.h \
   myowncode2.h \
   myowncode3.h \

SOURCES += \
   myowncode.cpp \
   myowncode2.cpp \
```

when I try to compile my project, it find the .h only if I put them directly in $${PACKAGE_SOURCES}/Shared/MyITK

if I "copy past" the source code form itk, which is organized like that:
/Modules/ModuleNames/SubModulesNames/include

is there a way to make QMake looking for .h in all subdirectories ?

according to Matt answers I tried:

```
ITKModules = Core Filtering IO Numerics Registration Segmentation

Core.submodules = Common  FiniteDifference  
IO.submodules = NIFTI ImageBase
Numerics.submodules = Eigen FEM NarrowBand NeuralNetworks
Registration.submodules = Common FEM
Segmentation.submodules = BioCell ConnectedComponents KLMRegionGrowing 

MyITK {
  CONFIG_FOUND += MyITK
  for(foo, ITKModules): for(bar, $${foo}.submodules) {
  INCLUDEPATH += $${PACKAGE_SOURCES}/Shared/MyITK/Modules/$${foo}/$${bar}/include
  }
  QMAKE_LIBDIR += $${PACKAGE_LIB}/MyITK
  win32:LIBS += ITKIONIFTI-4.13.lib \ 
    ITKCommon-4.13.lib \
    ITKBiasCorrection-4.13.lib \
    ITKBioCell-4.13.lib \
```

}

but it still can't link to the .h at VS compilation.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to make QMake looking for .h in all subdirectories ?

Actually you're trying to make your *compiler* look into all subdirectories, not `qmake`.

`qmake` itself has no built-in function to generate subdirs list. But you can prettify your `pro` a bit using loops:

```
modules = x1 x2 x3
x1.submodules = y1 y4
x2.submodules = y2 y5
x3.submodules = y3 y6
for(foo, modules): for(bar, $${foo}.submodules) {
    INCLUDEPATH += /Modules/$${foo}/$${bar}/include
}
```

Comment: thanks. is there a way to "print/check" what it has as includepath after this ?

Comment: actually I did the change in the .pri file and not the .pro. but I understand they are similar. it's just the .pro is my module. and in the .pri I put the dependencies from other libraries.

Comment: oh actually to print it was like cmake, so after closing the bracket of MyITK I did messge($$INCLUDEPATH) and I have this D:/Sources/Shared/MyITK/Core/Common/include D:/Sources/Shared/MyITK/Core/FiniteDifference/include D:/Sources/Shared/MyITK/Core/GPUCommon/include ... so I am "happy", except that when I want to built it doesn't find .h which are included in these folders